# Bootstrap-codeigniter-php-autocompletar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

please help me, I find no error.
The jQuery autocomplete is working fine but I want to see the results as a combo. get the data but does not show
thaks

VIEW

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[name=codigo]").autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/articulo/getarticulos",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            if (ui.item.id) {
                $("[name=codigo]").val(ui.item.codigo);
                return false;
            }
        },
        search: function (event, ui ) {
            $("[name=codigo]").val(0);
        }
    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6"> 
        <div class='input-group'>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span></span>                
            <input id="txtcodigo" name="codigo" type="text" placeholder="Codigo" value="" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```php
public function getarticulos()
{
    $q              = trim($this->input->get('term'));     
    $where          = array('like codigo' => $q);
    $productoresult = $this->articulo_model->All($where);
    $result         = array();

    foreach ($productoresult as $i => $articulo) {
        $result[$i]['id']           = $articulo->id;
        $result[$i]['codigo']       = $articulo->codigo;
        $result[$i]['descripcion']  = $articulo->descripcion;
        $result[$i]['precioactual'] = $articulo->precioactual;
    }          
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

MODEL

function `All` is from `CI_MODEL`

```
class Articulo_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('articulo', NULL, 'Articulo_Model');     
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the All method?

Comment: the ALL method is in the model class, i use codeigniter. system->core->Model ,

Comment: I understand You use CI but I never seen that. Is your data in a database? Why not use active record and the db class?